# Laravel Scheduler running only once

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduler, jobs

I'm trying to run a controller function every minute to update the status of my servers but my scheduler is only running once after updating all rows in the table. This is my first time using a task scheduler in Laravel. I tried running it on cmd and it says Running scheduled command: Closure and after all the table is updated the task stops.

```
//My Controller function to be called

public function updateServerScheduler()
{
  $servers = Server::all();
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

  foreach ($servers as $server)
  {
      //$server->firewall = @fsockopen($server->ip, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

      exec("ping -w 60 " . $server->ip, $output, $result);

      if($result != 0)
      {
        $server->status = 0;
        $server->latency = "None";
      }
      else
      {
        $server->status = 1;
        $server->latency = $this->pingDomain($server->ip);
      }

      $server->last_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $server->save();
  }
}


//My Kernel.php

namespace App\Console;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use Server;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
     protected $commands = [
       //
     ];
     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
     {

            $schedule->call(function () {
              $hc = new HomeController();
              $hc->updateServerScheduler();
            })->everyMinute();
     }

     protected function commands()
     {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
     }
}
```

Comment: did you add crontab  ? because php runs once if you want to run it every minute you need to define a cron job

Comment: No i didn't. I'm new to this scheduler can you teach me how to create a cron job in laravel ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

Create your command to run schedular and add it in kernel file.
ex.  $schedule->command('test')->everyMinute();

Comment: i already did this but it stops after updating all tables. I want it to run after every update.

Comment: It's continuously running but as all updates have done so can't find any changes.